# how to send database value from jsp to jsp without using submitting form

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am trying to send a database value from jsp to jsp but its not working

This is the code in my js file

```
 }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","st_proEdit.jsp?pro_id="+ str2 , true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
}
```

This is the code in my sending jsp

```
onclick="showHint1('st_proEdit.jsp', <%=rs.getString("pro_id")%>)"/>
```

This is the code in my receiving jsp

```
<%request.getParameter("pro_id");%>
```

Can anyone help me please

Comment: It would be helpful to see more of the code - but this line `onclick="showHint1('st_proEdit.jsp', <%=rs.getString("pro_id")%>)"` will output a value not wrapped in quotes - so unless it is a number it will be interpreted as a variable.

Comment: function showHint1(str1,str2) {
    if (str1.length == 0) { 
        document.getElementById("showHint1").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("showHint1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","st_proEdit.jsp?pro_id="+ str2 , true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}

Comment: if you debug `showHint1` what is the value of `str2` ?

Comment: the value of str2 should be <%=rs.getString("pro_id")%>

Comment: Yes, but when the script runs what is the actual value? As I said before, the JSP is inserting the string in to JavaScript as-is `value` vs `"value"`  - so it is probably being interpreted as a variable and not a string.